# Is it possible to covert swf to apk and ipa file using AIR SDK?

Tags: air, apk, flash, ipa, haxeflixel

I use FlashDevelop to make game using HaxeFlixel which handles multi-resolution and touch.

I've downloaded the merged SDK of Flex and AIR SDK but have no clue to convert.

I can easily compile to apk only if I  download the Android SDK, NDK which use up more than 1 GB of space.

I read somewhere says that I need AIR SDK to compile to iPad file.

I want to use only AIR SDK to compile to both apk (without Android DK things) and ipa file.

Comment: swf and apk/ipa files are very different by nature. i'd suggest creating an air project with your source and compiling that

Comment: I write the game in the Haxe language. Luckily, it can be easily translate to AS3 using command line. I just ask to know whether there's another way.

Comment: @MartonPallagi Also, the AS3 files from the libraries I use could be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not missing something here, but why are you trying to convert swf to apk when you can compile targeting directly to iOS target?

The whole point of using Haxe, is that you can target to misc platforms, including iOS, by

1. Exporting native code (Objective-C for iOS)
2. Compiling the exported native code, (using Hxcpp and Xcode for iOS)

The major advantage for **compiling native code**. is that after the compilation, your application will run much faster, better optimised for the targeted device, and way more reliably, compared to a converted swf.

For iOS targets, a full Xcode project will be created for you, so you can even use the Xcode's tools to test your app

more info about targeting to iOS on HaxeFlixel's [docs](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/ios/)

Comment: But I need a Mac to do what you said since I don't have one so convert swf is the the best solution.